# insert row and column labels into the matrix

Tags: matlab, label, row

for instance you have:

```
A = [1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4];

B = [5.5 6.6]

C = [7 8 9 10;
    11 12 13 14]
```

how would you insert A as the column label and B as the row label so it looks like this:

```
D =     
           1.1  2.2  3.3  4.4

     5.5    7    8    9    10

     6.6    11   12   13    14
```

I tried this code:

```
printmat(C,'sols',B(1,:),A(1,:))
```

however it says that column/row is not enough :(

by the way, size of C changes depending on the size of A and B so no fixed labels

please help

thanks!

Comment: @Dan, thanks, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dan, oh yeah i've seen that post. in that case the row/column labels are fixed they dont change. in my case, the row and column labels are changing like it increases and decreases. thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Only to display it nicely? To write to a text file? To write to Excel? Or do you really want to have this as a matrix to manipulate in Matlab and if so why? The answer will depend on your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
I dont know much about labeling. I'm quite sure that it is not possible to really leave out an element within a matrix. 
What i would do, what probably doesn't answer the question as you want to, is to concatenate the matrices and add a NaN as the first value of A, like this:

A = [Na 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5];

```
B = [5.5 6.6]
C = [7 8 9 10;
11 12 13 14]
Buff=[ B' C]
D=[A; Buff];
```

for concatenation take a look to this:

[creating-and-concatenating-matrices](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html)

Comment: thanks for that but the "D" part from your code it doesn't work as I wrote in the output

Comment: well, then what's different? in other words: what exaclty do you want as the output? shouldnt D be a matrix? Do you want to leave the last label empty? or is it just the printing-format-> have a look at Dan's comment on your question!

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works but it is not the same as the output that I wanted (check the question). it goes like this:

Comment: like u see how the column heading is indented after the row label? that is the output that i wanted. but in your code after trying it, it doesn't indent the heading it starts from the first cell. i want to keep the first cell blank..

Comment: alright, there I got something wrong :( Well I'll edit my answer, not sure if I have something that helps you....